# Terarria what happens with Crimson Seeds?

Tags: terraria

I recently spawned and killed the Eye of Cthulu, I got 2 crimson seeds, I planted them and it now says (when I ask my dryad) "Central City (my world) is now 7% Crimson! You are so close." What does this mean? Have I destroyed my world? What is happening? I am terrified.

Comment: You might have to move to Earth-2!

Answer (score 9):

To answer your question, I need to explain a couple of things first, starting with biomes. Biomes are defined when there are enough of a certain biome's specific blocks close together; so for example, a lot of snow blocks makes a snow biome, and a lot of crimson grass or Crimstone makes a Crimson biome.

Crimson biomes spawn naturally during world generation, they have a cave-like entrance to a deep opening in hard, unmineable Crimstone, where you can find tough enemies and Crimson Hearts. From the start of the game, Crimson will spread over grass, turning it red and expanding the biome, but cannot spread to any other kind of block, except for the vines and thorns it creates. In most cases, a Crimson biome will quickly get contained by a patch of stone that it cannot cross or something similar.

The Crimson Seeds you got from slaying the Eye of Cthulhu are related, but also not. When you plant a Crimson Seed, you create a single patch of Crimson-infected grass, and nothing else. Now, if left unattended, that patch can spread to more grass, but it's unlikely to create a biome because it most likely won't reach the amount of blocks needed to create a biome, since it cannot spread to stone, but only grass.

The Dryad gives you a status report on how much of the world is infected by the Crimson, as she would like to see the world completely cleansed of it. The two Crimson Seeds you planted are incredibly small compared to the naturally occurring biomes, and the fact that you planted them is not related to the fact that the Dryad is telling you about how much Crimson is in the world.

Comment: Also Crimson/corruption cannot spread on hallow

Answer (score 1):

> "The Crimson is a hazardous surface biome that presents a red gore theme, in contrast to the Corruption's purple diseased wasteland theme.
>   The tools, weapons and armor obtained via Crimson materials have minor advantages over those obtained via Corruption materials, but has the trade-off that Crimson enemies are slightly stronger"

[Source](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/The_Crimson)

Comment: Okay, but is it going to turn my world into a Crimson Biome? Also, should I destroy all the Crimson?

Comment: @Pietro Your world already has a crimson biome. Go exploring more.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer I know I found two of them, I mean, is it going to turn every single biome in my world into a Crimson one?

Comment: @Pietro I'm going to make my own answer because you seem very confused.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing will happen with crimson or corrupt seeds until you have entered "Hard mode" but when you do they will spread the crimson or corrupt biome though out that area. And what your driad is telling you is the percentage of your world that is crimson and once you enter hard mode there will be a hollow biome the more hollow and less crimson you have the better things she will say about you.